# Error 500 when using Google_PredictionService Google API sample

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-prediction

Updated:

My project is to be able to provide a web based application which allows the visitor to upload/download/delete files using GoogleDrive. The project requires it to be server based, which does not require credentials from the user to be able to perform these functions.

In a nutshell, the web application stores the files on a single dedicated google drive account, instead of storing the files on the server.

I researched Google's developer site, and was directed to using the example below as a starting point, to configure the PHP application to use the Drive Account I set up.

I followed the instructions per Google's page:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts

When I execute this script, I am receiving the following 500 error:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 3 passed to
>   Google_HostedmodelsServiceResource::predict() must be an instance of
>   Google_Input, none given, called in
>   /data/sites/scott/htdocs/dfs_development/drive/serviceAccount.php on
>   line 62 and defined in
>   /data/sites/scott/htdocs/dfs_development/apis/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PredictionService.php
>   on line 36

What am I doing wrong here? I am uncertain what $project variable should hold, and it seems the predict() function needs 3 args, however I am at a loss to know what it should be.

Here is my code, which I obtained from the URL above. Thank you in advance for your response.

```
require_once '../apis/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../apis/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PredictionService.php';

// Set your client id, service account name, and the path to your private key.
// For more information about obtaining these keys, visit:
// https://developers.google.com/console/help/#service_accounts

const CLIENT_ID = '##########.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = '########@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

// Make sure you keep your key.p12 file in a secure location, and isn't
// readable by others.
const KEY_FILE = 'pathto/secretlystored/######-privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My Google Drive");

// Set your cached access token. Remember to replace $_SESSION with a
// real database or memcached.
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Load the key in PKCS 12 format (you need to download this from the
// Google API Console when the service account was created.
$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction'),
    $key)
);


$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$service = new Google_PredictionService($client);

// Prediction logic:
$id = 'dfslocalhost';
$predictionData = new Google_InputInput();
$predictionData->setCsvInstance(array('Je suis fatigue'));

$input = new Google_Input();
$input->setInput($predictionData);

$result = $service->hostedmodels->predict($id, $input); ## 500 ERROR occurs here.. 

print '<h2>Prediction Result:</h2><pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';

// We're not done yet. Remember to update the cached access token.
// Remember to replace $_SESSION with a real database or memcached.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thats because Google_PredictionService API has not actived in your google API console dev.

Comment: Thanks, byt in my Google APIs services tab I have the following enabled:

Drive API
Drive SDK
Prediction API

What else should I be checking to see I have this set correctly?